# What type parameters should I use to make List.map work with delimited continuations?

Tags: scala, delimited-continuations

I'm basically following the example given at the [Scala API page for delimited continuations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.continuations.package).  The code below works fine:

```scala
import scala.util.continuations._
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

val sessions = new HashMap[Int, Int=>Unit]
def ask(prompt: String): Int @cps[Unit] = shift {
  ret: (Int => Unit) => {
    val id = sessions.size
    printf("%s\nrespond with: submit(0x%x, ...)\n", prompt, id)
    sessions += id -> ret
  }
}

def submit(id: Int, addend: Int): Unit = {
  sessions.get(id) match {
    case Some(continueWith) => continueWith(addend)
  }
}

def go = reset {
  println("Welcome!")
  val first = ask("Please give me a number")
  val second = ask("Please enter another number")
  printf("The sum of your numbers is: %d\n", first + second)
}
```

However, when I modify `go` to the following:

```scala
def go = reset {
  println("Welcome!")
  List("First?","Second?").map[Int @cps[Unit]](ask)
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: wrong number of type parameters for method map: [B, That](f: String => B)
(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[String],B,That])That
             List("First?","Second?").map[Int @cps[Unit]](ask)
                                         ^
```

Adding `Any` as a second type parameter doesn't help.  Any idea what types I should be supplying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the closest thing I could work out.  It uses shiftR to reify the continuation rather than reset it, uses a foldRight to construct the suspended continuation chain, uses a shift/reset block to get the continuation after the suspension, and an "animate" method to kick off the suspended continuation.

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.util.continuations._

val sessions = new HashMap[Int, (Unit=>Unit, Int)]
val map = new HashMap[Int, Int]

def ask(pair:(String, Int)) = pair match { 
  case (prompt, index) => shiftR { (ret: Unit => Unit) => {
    val id = sessions.size
    printf("%s\nrespond with: submit(0x%x, ...)\n", prompt, id)
    sessions += id -> (ret, index)
    ()
  }}
}

def submit(id: Int, addend: Int): Unit = {
  sessions.get(id) match {
    case Some((continue, index)) => { map.put(index, addend); continue() }
  }
}

def sum(m:HashMap[Int,Int]) : Int = {
  m.fold[(Int, Int)]((0, 0))((a, b) => (0, {a._2+b._2}))._2
}

type Suspended = ControlContext[Unit,Unit,Unit]

class AnimateList(l:List[Suspended]) {
  def suspend(k: => Unit) = (c: Unit) => k
  def animate(k:Unit => Unit): Unit = {
    l.foldRight(k)(
      (elem: Suspended, acc: Unit => Unit) => suspend(elem.fun(acc, ex => ())))()
  }
}

implicit def listToAnimateList(l:List[Suspended]) = new AnimateList(l)

reset { 
  val conts = List("First?","Second?","Third?").zipWithIndex.map(ask)
  shift { conts.animate }
  println(sum(map))
}
```

Comment: The solution above only captures the part of the continuation that comes after, not before.  [This solution](http://pastie.org/private/exrygt9jw5k1k6i8jwywzq) captures the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that this is simply not possible without creating a CPS-transformed `map` method on `List`: the CPS annotations make the compiler turn your methods “inside out” in order to pass the continuation back to where it is needed and the standard `List.map` does not obey the transformed contract. If you want to have your mind wrapped in Klein bottles for a while you may look at the class files produced from your source, in particular the method signatures.

This is the primary reason why the CPS plugin will never be a complete generic solution to this problem, which is not due to a deficiency but caused by an inherent mismatch between “straight” code and continuation passing style.

Comment: So if I implement my own `map` method using a while loop rather than the built-in method, it'll work because it can CPS transform that?

Comment: The CPS plugin is limited (and not completely bug-free in my experience), I would suggest keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give correct parameter for the CanBuildFrom implicit to be found:

```
List("First?","Second?").map[Int @cps[Unit], List[Int @cps[Unit]](ask)
```

But do you really need to be explicit about type? maybe just do `.map(ask)` will work.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions work.  The compiler responds to the first suggestion with `type arguments do not conform to method map's type parameter bounds` and to the second with `no type parameters for method map exist so that it can be applied to arguments`.  Does the latter mean it's not possible to make this work?

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm afraid I don't understand why exactly. But it might be possible to provide a 'CanBuildFrom' instance that satisfy the needed type. What if you just add `implicit val cbf: CanBuildFrom[List[String], Int @cps[Unit], List[Int @cps[Unit]] = null` just before the line doing map?

Comment: It can't find the type `CanBuildFrom`

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

Comment: Of course, sorry.  It gives the same error "no type parameters for method map exist..."